# ASP>NET Page performance issue

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net page which has 4 grid views connecting to mysql database for data population. The average response time for a round trip to the server is 20.55 seconds. That is way too much time. I have since applied the HTTP Compression GZip to improve the speed,I don't see any improvement in load time. Any suggestion, ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Ive also used pagination, but no effect.

Comment: maybe u should do a little profiling to check whats taking so much time...

Comment: How much data are we talking about?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Where is the bottleneck? Is the server waiting on the queries to execute? Is the response 10 megabytes?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to nail it to down where it is taking time. Debug the application and measure the response time of the sql queries and the databind operation seperately. If its the query or the stored procedure that is taking time you should add indexes or refine the query to improve the performance. But if its databinding to gird thats taking time(which I dont really suspect) post some code here without which we cannot help much on that.

Comment: You didn't include any code. Go and time your database queries

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel said, start with profiling the page to see exactly where the time is spent.

Namely, execute the queries that the grid views run independently of the page.  How long do they take to run?  If most of your time is here, then try and figure out how to make them more performant.

Second, you might consider using something other than a grid view.  Those can store a tremendous amount of information in view state.  Maybe look into using repeaters or something similar depending on the functionality you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to check how long your database queries are taking to run. Until you know how long they are taking it is hard to guess at what might be taking the time.